# show alternate image when google street view is unavailable

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I Currently have an if statement allowing me to determining if streetview is unavailable or not. I would like to change to an image if street view is unavailable. Currently when streetview is unavailable I get a div with a grey background-color. If i can remove this grey background or any other work around to show an image in place of it.

What have I tried.

```
else{
// streetview not available
panoramic.setVisible(false);

var div = document.getElementById('streetview');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<img src="randompic.png" width="42" height="42">';
//Note this does display the image but with grey background

div.style.background-color='rgb(255, 255, 255)';
div.style.color='white'`
//These seem to have no affect
```

I also tried placing a script at the end of the document

```
  <script>
  document.getElementById("streetview").style.color="white";
  document.getElementById("streetview").style.background-color='rgb(255, 255, 255)';
  </script>
```

Still after page load the BG color of the div is grey...

My thoughts is that goolge is setting the BG color  after this script has run but im unsure

Thanks
JT

Comment: just a remark : I don't really think it is a good practice to qualify you variale with java script reserved words such as `div`

Comment: I would agree im just testing this out right now though.

Comment: `div` is no problem and it's not `Javascript`'s reserved word, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).

Comment: What if you set the background and everything else with `css` by default and don't run `else` ?

Comment: The backgound-color of this div when not set at all in my code. Still get changed/set to grey...Im sure google is doing this on page load...

Comment: try waiting til the google script has fired

Comment: Best practices of doing such? How do you suggest I wait.

Comment: With the google streetview script being is in the head of the document. Am I silly/wrong to assume that the script I wrote to set the BG color is in the body and thus it runs afterwards?